# How to organize several independent git repos as a tree inside another folder (or repo) in git - don't need submodules?

Tags: git, github, directory, tree, bitbucket

the gist of my question is about *organizing* my independent repos as a tree within git.

I only care about being able to place several repos inside a folder within BB

(Or several repos inside another repo, I don't care.)

Also don't care about tracking, say, push history to all three repos from one central place.  The repos are independent.

Submodules and such are way too much headache for the dead-simple thing I want to do.

I just want git to mirror the way I have my code organized on my local drive.

The big reason: Otherwise I would have to flatten out my tree in git.

I would have to give my git repos clunky names like **projectOne-crappyOldDeprecatedVersion-perlStuff**

Suppose my code looks like this, with a crappy / new / and common organization like so:

```
projectOne (can be a repo or a folder, don't care)
      crappyOldDeprecatedVersion (independent repo)
            perlStuff
            jqueryStuff
            rubyStuff
      shinyNewVersion (independent repo)
            javaBackEnd
            nodeServerSide
            reactFacade
      commonToCrappyAndShiny (independent repo)
            dbStoredProcedures
```

How can I accomplish this in git?

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with having the sctructure like that where the dir `projectOne` is just a normal folder and not a git repo?

Comment: You haven't explained what specifically about "just do it" is a problem here.

Comment: The github interface - to which I am admittedly a newbie - does not show an obvious way to create a repo within a folder, or a repo within a repo.  The only time you get a "create repo" button is when you are at root level, not when you are inside a folder or the root repo. That is, if I click on projectOne then I am inside projectOne and cannot create the repo crappyOldDeprecatedVersion because the "create repo" button has disappeared.

Comment: Github isn't your main workspace. Github is where you publish the results of your work, not where you construct those results. For super-easy fixups a web ui's fine, it's not meant for anything heavier.

Comment: Did I understand correctly : `crappy` and `shiny` both depend on `common` ? If so, the sentence "the repos are independant" should be rephrased, shouldn't it ?

Comment: They are independent insofar as git is concerned. That is, I am not looking to implement central GIT tracking of both shiny and common. If a code change breaks crappy, I don't care (for the purposes of this stackoverflow question), all I want is for git to allow me to create shiny, crappy, and common inside of ProjectOne.